# Robot moves to certain coordinate point with rclpy and set multiple goals?

Tags: ros, ros2, python

i'm new user in ros2, i'm trying to send robot to certain points, i dont understand how to do it, i tried many codes and nothing works, can you help me with code?

Tnx!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to move robot from poin A to point B, this is what i need.